# CSV with latitude and longitude to a spatial points with QGIS 1.8

Tags: qgis

I have a CSV file with latitude and longitude of several addresses and a shapefile of a region. I want to plot the points of the CSV file into the shapefile. But I don't know how to transform these latitude and longitude columns into spatial points with QGIS 1.8

Comment: check this question. It is closed but it has some useful information:http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55195/adding-a-delimited-text-layer-with-qgis-1-1-0/55221#55221

Answer (score 2):

Enable the "Add Delimited Text Layer" plugin from the Plugins->Manage plugins... menu. See also the [Import from CSV](http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/import_csv.php) tutorial.